# Can I shift focus to a div through CSS alone?

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to shift focus to a div by default through pure CSS, and not using JavaScript?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there isn't.

In normal circumstances, a div can't receive the focus at all, and CSS lacks anything to set the focus.

Answer (score 4):

No CSS does not offer anything on focus. I know you said no JavaScript, but how easy:

```
document.getElementById('exampleId').focus();
```

Comment: For newbies, note that 'div' is not selecting a `<div>`. It is selecting any one tag that has it's `id = div` like `<li id='div'>` so it's a very confusing example. I edited to remove the confusion but @TylerH rolled back (with no reason given). Why????

Comment: @www-0av-Com If someone doesn't understand from **`getElementById`** that they are getting the ID, then what makes you think the same instruction phrased in a different way will help them understand (this is a rhetorical question, to be clear)? The edit you made seemed both unnecessary and overly verbose, reducing the quality of the answer. It's valid to have a concern, but it should be posted as a comment rather than a suggested edit. Suggested edits should be reserved for clear, unambiguous improvements to posts.

Comment: @TylerH -- read this. https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/ ... So you don't welcome inexperienced people.  That's rhetorical too. The only reason I ever come to stack exchange is because sometimes I have to program in something I don't know well. This is is confusing but I will settle for something less confusing like foo. And by the way, that answer will only work if contenteditable is on.

Answer (score 4):

First thing you have to remember that by default in CSS div is not focusable element means focus pseudo class will not work directly with the div element and only elements that can receive focus, such as input, select, a,textarea .

But there are some ways exist which you can use and can make your div focusable.

First Way: use tabindex attribute
Example:

```
<div tabindex="0">I am Small box</div>
```

Second way: use contenteditable attribute
Example:

```
<div contenteditable="true">Hello I am DivBox</div>
```

Complete source code for better understanding:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" 
content="width=device-width, 
initial-scale=1">
<title></title
<style>
div:focus {
border: 2px solid blue;
background-color: green;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>
<div contenteditable="true">Hello 
I am Div</div>

<br>

<div tabindex="0">I am Small 
box</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Other ways: using JavaScript

```
<script>
const Anyname = 
document.getElementById('Name');
Anyname.focus();
</script>
```

Using these ways you can Swift focus on div element.

Answer (score 3):

Since none of the answers here worked for me (although I wanted focus on an input, not a div) I'll post one that does work:

autofocus

just like this:

```
<input autofocus>
```

Of course, the OP is asking for how to make this work with a div, which this doesn't. As was previously mentioned, contenteditable="yes" *will* make the div focusable, but this unfortunately doesn't work either:

```
<div contenteditable="yes" autofocus>
  This doesn't work!!
</div>
```

In my opinion, this is kind of an oversight in HTML5, this div should act like an input field. However, for the time being, it seems that javascript is required for this to happen.

Answer (score 1):

Any element can receive focus if it is contenteditable. However, CSS doesn't recognize :focus pseudoclasses for elements other than input, select, a, textarea and button.

Answer (score 0):

although it depends on what you're trying to achieve, you could apply a `:hover` pseudo-class on a div if you want to visually highlight it.